# Facebook login failed returing 404 error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am accessing FB outh as below

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + token,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(jqXHR, text_status, strError) {
        alert(text_status + " " + strError);
    },
    success: function(data) {

        checkF(data);
    }
});
```

in console it shows

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<some tokenm>&expires_in=5168251 404 (Not Found)
```

If i past this url directly in browser i get

```
{
   "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "email": "XXXXXXXX\u0040gmail.com",
   "first_name": "Veer",
   "gender": "male",
   "last_name": "MB",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/XXXXXX/",
   "locale": "en_GB",
   "name": "Veer MB",
   "timezone": 5.5,
   "updated_time": "2015-03-11T08:40:38+0000",
   "verified": false
}
```

One more strange issue same code working in desktop but not in laptop

Comment: Have you considered using the official JavaScript SDK? Can you get the full response body of the 404 request?

Comment: SOLVED! I was using wrong email id to login thats wht it was happening.